# Is it possible to generate SSIS derived column transformation automatically?

Tags: ssis

I need to create hundreds derived columns transformation in the control. However, I already have the meta data in a text file. Is it possible to generate the markup code of the control from my meta data and insert it into the dtsx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages can be manipulated programmatically. [Start reading this msdn section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx).